# Get all databases and convert to String Array

Tags: java, sql, database, arrays, jooq

How to add all the databases from server to String array in java? I am using JOOQ api to execute SQL statements and i need to get all the databases in comboBox where i can select specific database.

Comment: What is the underlying database system?

Comment: MySQL, runs under Linux server

Comment: "show databases" this command gives all the database names

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-databases.html

Comment: @HRigger: i have several databases on my server and i need to get all databases listed in my comboBox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several options. For instance, you could use the generated
classes from jOOQ-meta (or generate the information_schema yourself),
and then write:

```
Factory create = new Factory(connection, dialect);
String[] array =
create.selectDistinct(TABLES.TABLE_SCHEMA)
      .from(TABLES)
      .fetchArray(TABLES.TABLE_SCHEMA);
```

The same can be achieved through plain SQL, of course:

```
String[] array =
create.selectDistinct(field("table_schema"))
      .from("information_schema.TABLES") // Watch for case-sensitivity on MySQL
      .fetchArray(0, String.class);
```

Or, using the `SHOW TABLES` command:

```
String[] array =
create.fetch("SHOW TABLES")
      .intoArray(0, String.class);
```

Another option would be to read from JDBC's DatabaseMetaData:

```
Connection connection = ...;
DatabaseMetaData meta = connection.getMetaData();
String[] array = create.fetch(meta.getSchemas()).intoArray(0, String.class);
```

In jOOQ 3.0, you will also be able to read the meta data through the jOOQ API:

```
List<Schema> schemas = create.meta().getSchemas();
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, i have solved the problem using the last option.